# How to update an object field inside an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, graphql

I am using GraphQL to update an object that stays inside an array which is in another array. So my Schema is like this

```
const InstalmentsGroupSchema = new Schema(
  {
    offer: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Offer"
    },
    instalments: [
      {
        instalmentCount: { type: Number },
        instalmentAmout: { type: Number },
        dueTo: { type: Date },
        observations: { type: String },
        requestedAmount: { type: Number },
        acceptedRequest: { type: Boolean }
      }
    ]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

What I want to do is to update the fields of an instalment like this

```
updateInstalmentGroup: async (
    _,
    { _id, instalmentId, ...args },
    { user }
  ) => {
    try {
      await requireAuth(user);
      const instalmentGroup = await InstalmentsGroup.findOne({
        _id
      });

      if (!instalmentGroup) {
        throw new Error("Not found!");
      }

      const instalments = instalmentGroup.instalments;


      Object.assign(
        instalments,
        instalments.map(instalment =>
          instalment.id === instalmentId ? args : instalment
        )
      );

      return instalmentGroup.save();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
};
```

Now the problem comes when I try to update it in here:

This part is updating but replace the all fields. So if I update `observations` field will remove the others

```
instalments.map(instalment =>
  instalment.id === instalmentId ? args : instalment
)
```

If I try this way will not update at all

```
instalments.map(instalment =>
  instalment.id === instalmentId ? {...instalment, args} : instalment
)
```

**SOLVED**

```
const instalmentToUpdate = instalments.find(
  instalment => instalment.id === instalmentId
);

Object.assign(instalmentToUpdate, args);
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I try this way will not update at all
>
> `instalments.map(instalment =>
>        instalment.id === instalmentId ? {...instalment, args} : instalment
>   )`

It "doesn't update" (updates in fact) because `args` is an array, try this:

```
instalments.map(instalment =>
  instalment.id === instalmentId ? {...instalment, ...args} : instalment )
```

Comment: Even this way is not working, I've updated my post with the solution I got